# Encode data fields, programmatically execute trade transaction

Tags: contract-invocation, raw-transaction, python, pyethereum

I'm trying to encode the data fields according to the contract ABI using [Pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum) in python.  I'm making a raw transaction.  I'm successfully able send ether from one address to another by signing a transaction and then sending it raw.  Now i'm trying to execute a trade function on a contract, hence the need for the data field encoding.

I feel like there should be some encode function built into Pyethereum but I cannot find it.  Should I encode these manually instead?  How should I go about this?

```
Function: trade(address tokenGet, uint256 amountGet, address tokenGive, uint256 amountGive, uint256 expires, uint256 nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint256 amount)

MethodID: 0x0a19b14a
[0]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[1]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002e8678fcd97f4000
[2]:000000000000000000000000e41d2489571d322189246dafa5ebde1f4699f498
[3]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a2a15d09519be00000
[4]:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000401042
[5]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008d64da5d
[6]:00000000000000000000000049b85d124dde84d651e0efb02f738c5e9c484a89
[7]:000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b
[8]:f92d42545bd87995b4af1d3edf225dab7515a31350b755ef4761d6de160722de
[9]:3352d494554c036bd798fd287e4c2ac68371adf653a2dd6252ec7625555c1a52
[10]:00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a29e1e7c600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wrote a [blog post](https://thomasclowes.com/creating-the-input-data-for-an-ethereum-contract-function-call/) about this a few days ago :)

The Ethereum Wiki documentation on the matter is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#use-of-dynamic-types).

None of your inputs are of unknown length and as such it is simply a case of encoding the input arguments and padding them appropriately.

Comment: Thank you!  It's all making sense now.  Great timing on the blog post ;-)

Comment: Link only answers are not very useful in stackexchange, if the site is down temporarily or permanently we will lost access to a good answer. Perhaps you can put the main idea here and use the link as a complement. Nice page by the way!